# Checking if form input is filled and hiding/unhiding div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have some problem with hiding/unhiding the `div` element. I have `input` element who is filled by datepicker. If that `input` element is empty (always on start) the `div` element should be hidden. I have this code:

```
$("#input#date_from").keyup(function () {
   if ($(this).val()) {
      $("#return_section").show();
   }
   else {
      $("#return_section").hide();
   }
});
```

but it didn't work. The `div` element is still visible, and I don't know where is the problem?

Thanks, for any help!

Comment: Is the first hash `#` symbol in `#input#date_from` a typo?

Comment: in oryginal code i don't have `#` - mistake when coping code

Comment: Is the <div> hidden on page load with `display:none;` or equivalent? This code would only hide it when you delete the last character from the input.

Comment: I added the `display:none` code to `css`. The `div` is hidden now, but when I pick the date from the input field the `div` element is still hidden.

Comment: try using `change` instead of `keyup`

Comment: can you change the test to `$(this).val() !== ''` (see answer below)
..and maybe add console.log or alert in each branch of the if statement to see if this is triggered at all?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17924/discussion-between-st3inn-and-adrian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `#date_from` input is filled by the datepicker, it's probably better to use `change()` instead of `keyup()` as it watches for a change in the value of the input, as opposed to keyboard strokes. I would also explicitly check if the input field is empty.

```
$("#date_from").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
        $("#return_section").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#return_section").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `#` at the start of the selector, which is unneeded as you are selecting the `input` element, not an element with `id` of 'input`. Try this:

```
$("#date_from").keyup(function () {
   if ($(this).val()) {
      $("#return_section").show();
   }
   else {
      $("#return_section").hide();
   }
});
```